# Unity Character flies above the ground whenever I start my game

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

Every time I start my game the character starts to rise and fly above the ground. I don't understand how to fix it. I've tried to move the ground up but nothing's changed. 2D game if it matters.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player_Controller: MonoBehaviour
{
  public float speed = 0.1f;

  private void Update()
  {
      transform.position += new Vector3(speed, 0, 0) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
      transform.position += new Vector3(0, speed, 0) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

      if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)//если влево
      {
           GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
      }
      if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)//если вправо
      {
           GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
      }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the Rigidbody Component to your Character GameObject, then enable gravity in the component and your character should just fall on the ground.

EDIT: If you find your character in the Unity Hierarchy (left hand side of the screen by default) and then to the inspector window (right hand side of the screen by default. At the bottom of the inspector, there should be an ‘Add Component’ button. Click that button and then search ‘Rigidbody’ in the search field that appears. Add the Rigidbody Component. By default, the enable gravity option should be ticked but if it isn’t, just make sure you tick that box. When you run your game with gravity enabled, gravity should act on the GameObject with the ‘Rigidbody’ Component, pulling it to the ground

Also, make sure that you follow the same process as above to add the ‘Mesh Collider’ Component to your platform/ground - this will make your ground a ‘Physical’ object which will prevent your character falling straight through it

Hope this helps - let me know if it doesn’t work

Comment: I'm so glad that you decided to help me. I'm novice so I don't actually know how to eneble gravity. Could you tell me how to do it plz?))

Comment: If you find your character in the Unity Hierarchy (left hand side of the screen by default) and then to the inspector window (right hand side of the screen by default. At the bottom of the inspector, there should be an ‘Add Component’ button. Click that button and then search ‘Rigidbody’ in the search field that appears. Add the Rigidbody Component. By default, the enable gravity option should be ticked but if it isn’t, just make sure you tick that box. When you run your game with gravity enabled, gravity should act on the GameObject with the ‘Rigidbody’ Component, pulling it to the ground

Comment: Make sure you check my edited Answer as well

Comment: There are rigidbody and rigidbody2D. I am using Rigidbody 2D. There is only Gravity Scale. I can't use just Rigidbody because I also use Box Collider 2D and they can't work together

Comment: Oh I have fixed it!!! The problem was in the box collider! Thanks anyway))